# Python: Changing the number next to the variable in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

let's say we have,

```
 x1 = lst[0:20000]
 x2 = lst[0:20000]
 x3 = lst[0:20000]
 x4 = lst[0:20000]

 y1 = lst[0:20000]
 y2 = lst[0:20000]
 y3 = lst[0:20000]
 y4 = lst[0:20000]
```

I want to use one for loop to go through all the variables x1,...,x4.

```
 for i in range(20000):
   varX = x1.iloc[i]
   varY = y1.iloc[i]
```

How would I change the number of x1 to x2 to x3 etc.. and y1, y2, y3, etc.. in this case? I may need to use while loop to count. something like,

```
j = 1
while j < 5:
   for i in range(20000):
       varX = x1.iloc[I]
       varY = y1.iloc[i]
   j+=1
```

But my question is how would I change the 1 next to x x1.iloc[i] to x2.iloc[i] each time in the loop? precisely, how would I put j into here x(j).iloc[i] ?

Comment: Put the lists into a list?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

```
for x, y in zip((x1, x2, x3, x4), (y1, y2, y3, y4)):
    for i in range(20000):
        varX = x.iloc[i]
        varY = y.iloc[i]
```

It's better to put variables in the list when you create them, rather than temporarily gather them together when you want to use them together.

There are also ways to realize your idea, for example, use `globals` to get the global dictionary, or use `eval` to parse strings. But this is not recommended. You only need to know, but never use them in practice (Pretend you don't know they exist):

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    x = globals()[f'x{i}']   # or eval(f'x{i}')
    y = globals()[f'y{i}']
    for j in range(20000):
        varX = x.iloc[j]
        varY = y.iloc[j]
```

Comment: definitely don't go the `globals` route if you can at all avoid it! the `x1, x2` and so on should not be global, nor should you depend on their names.

Comment: Do not use `globals()`, that's always *(almost)* a bad idea. Variables should not be accessed by it's name.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to remind it's a bad idea.

Comment: Use `zip` @AmalNasir

Comment: I wonder if this is a good idea if I have for example many files like 50 or more?

Comment: When you create variables, you should put them in the list instead of using multiple variables. @AmalNasir